# Access remote docker daemon via ssh using Docker SDK for golang

Tags: docker

I am trying to access a remote docker daemon using ssh. I managed to do this using docker cli.

docker -H ssh://user@host images

Is there a way to do the same using Golang Docker SDK?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After going through Docker CLI source code, I managed to do the above using Golang Docker SDK. Below is a code snippet.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/docker/cli/cli/connhelper"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main(){

    helper, err := connhelper.GetConnectionHelper("ssh://user@host:22")

    if err != nil{
        return
    }

    httpClient := &http.Client{
        // No tls
        // No proxy
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DialContext: helper.Dialer,
        },
    }

    var clientOpts []client.Opt

    clientOpts = append(clientOpts,
        client.WithHTTPClient(httpClient),
        client.WithHost(helper.Host),
        client.WithDialContext(helper.Dialer),

    )

    version := os.Getenv("DOCKER_API_VERSION")

    if version != "" {
        clientOpts = append(clientOpts, client.WithVersion(version))
    } else {
        clientOpts = append(clientOpts, client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
    }


    cl, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(clientOpts...)


    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to create docker client")
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(cl.ImageList(context.Background(), types.ImageListOptions{}))

}
```